# How do I populate an iOS picker with all languages?

Tags: ios, localization, datapicker

I can't seem to find anything on this, a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.
I would like a picker (or picker view?) for selecting a language that shows 2 columns: language name in own language and language name in localized language.

Comment: That doesn't seem to me to be a normal picker view. But, first, of course you would need a list of all the languages, as well as mappings for each language to the localized versions of the other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSLocale to achieve this. Some manipulation of the codes can give you both localized version and its own language.

I have a project very close to what you want to achieve using UIPickerView. There is no display in the language itself though.

https://github.com/tooniz/LanguagePicker